# Перенос данных из одной БД в другую

Tags: база-данных

Доброго времени суток.
Мне нужно переносить данные из одной БД в другую, попутно выполняя преобразование. Может кто поделиться best practice как такие приложения пишутся и код организуется? Писать свое на коленке можется, но не хочется велосипедить.

Comment: а какой язык вы планирует использовать? сколько данных?

Comment: какая база данных?

Comment: да это не важно, я о принципах и общих решениях

Answer (score 1):

Подобные вещи называются Data Pipeline. Но если данных немного и это одноразовая задача, то смыла их использовать нет. Так как вы больше времени потратите на изучение вопроса, чем на использование.

Comment: Вот тут https://github.com/transfer-framework/transfer интересное решение. Есть исполнитель, который выполяет задания одно за другим, а само задание это конвеер, на вход которого подаются данные, а на выходе куда-то складируются.